# python tabulate: display blank cell for specific values

Tags: python, numpy, pretty-print, tabulate

I have this numpy array

```
import numpy as np
from tabulate import tabulate

data  = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
data2 = tabulate(data, tablefmt='fancy_grid')
print(data2)

╒═══╤═══╕
│ 1 │ 2 │
├───┼───┤
│ 3 │ 4 │
╘═══╧═══╛
```

I'm interested in a cleaner display of my table while ignoring values I'm not interested in. How can I print blank cells for specific values? For example, blanks for all 2 values in the array, like this:

```
╒═══╤═══╕
│ 1 │   │
├───┼───┤
│ 3 │ 4 │
╘═══╧═══╛
```

Comment: You could write a wrapper function that converts the numpy array to a list of lists, then manually changes all of a certain element to `" "`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to `'U'` or `'S'` dtype and explicitly replace the special values with `''`:

```
from tabulate import tabulate                
 
data  = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])             
data2 = tabulate(np.where(data==2,'',data.astype('U')), tablefmt='fancy_grid') 
print(data2)                                                                  
╒═══╤═══╕
│ 1 │   │
├───┼───┤
│ 3 │ 4 │
╘═══╧═══╛
```

Comment: Awesome, modifying it from the source. It works, thank you!